# How to read and understand the structure of .LED files?

Tags: xml, database, led

I need to become able to generate files with .led extension. Hence, i need to understand the structure of those files.

So far, i have been creating very simple LED files with LEDEdit and trying to read those files in Hex characters in order to catch the logic. However, i suppose i should use a different approach. Since the information i found about LED files are irrelevant with my approach. Informations are like those:

".led files which is an XML file with image date in base64 format"

"the .led file format. It uses a an odd format (IMO anyway) of stuffing the ON bit x/y coordinates into a 32-bit field (x into upper 16 bits, y into lower) and then converting that binary information to base64 and then into the final XML encoding."

From these definitions i understand i should read the file with XML but, i am not sure about how to do it. Because i can't read the files in ascii properly, so i can't use a conversion between ascii and XML.

I am open to any advice about how to approach to problem. Below is a sample image of files in Hex characters.

Thank you for your help.. [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2MtL.png)

Comment: See following webpage : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70732/read-and-decode-led-file

Comment: Thank you , i have seen that page but that is not what i exactly looking for.There they share their guesses abput file and then last comment suggests another method.
 I want to learn about how should i approach to file. How can i open it at XML format or Base64 format.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.  What do you want the xml file to look like?  You can make convert the byte[] LED data to a packed string using :  string innertext = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)

Comment: Yes, this  innertext = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)  this can be useful. What i trying to do is examining the file with the right method for that file in order to analyze it's structure.

Untill now, i was trying to examine it with Notepad++, Hex editor. However, i started to think, it is not the right method for this file.

Comment: As additional information, http://doityourselfchristmas.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-27163.html is a thread with more information. Snippets: "the .led export files has a form of encryption which basically requires the controller to be matched to the software used to create the file." "the encryption option of the program". "the files are .swf or Shockwave Flash Object files". "they absolutely are not just .SWF files."

Comment: Note that the sample screenshot here, combined with the examples attached to linked https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/70732/252526, seem to show that an .led file has sections that start with 'rzbv' or 'rzbv001' or something like that, and those that start with 'xbltk' or 'xbltk-0000' or something like that.